# How to view the PPPoE password inside a Huawei Router?

Tags: router, passwords, pppoe

I have an HG8247H router and I want to find out the PPPoE password set by my ISP inside the router for the possibility of using Bridge function. I have already tried looking for the password in the configuration file but the PPPoE password seems to be encrypted there although the configuration file itself isn't.

Is there any way of seeing the password?

Comment: If you are talking about a password that is for the router interface then most people would just reset the router and login with the default one.  If you are talking about a password required by the router to log into your ISP then most people would contact their ISP if there is a problem of not remembering the password and they could perhaps email you it.

Comment: Also i'm no expert but a PPP password and a password to access a function of a router seem to me to be different things.  To access what you describe as a function of a router, would typically require that you can log into the router, so a password for the router interface, nothing to do with PPP.

Comment: @barlop I’m talking about the PPPoE password that you enter for dialing a connection once you’ve already logged in to the router.

Comment: No, probably you can't see it. Try to ask your service provider for it. If they don't give it to you, then mining it out can even be against contact conditions.

Comment: @AsadMoeen if it's behind asterisks then you might be able to see it with chrome's element inspector on the webpage, but it seems you don't see it behind asterisks..

Comment: Since what you actually want to do is bridge the thing and you perhaps fear a reset and losing the PPP password, You might be able to export the configuration including password. (though there might not be a safe way to test that it has exported the password!) but if it did you could then import the configuration file if at some point the router lost the password as a result of bridging. Also worth finding out if the router would indeed lose the password after having done bridging.

Comment: @barlop the password is within the pppoe page. I just can’t get it out. The plain text method in page source works for other modems, just not Huawei. Can I do something with http headers when I submit the page?

Comment: @AsadMoeen I don't think so.. as I don't think the password would be sent via http.. the closest thing to catching the thing might be somehow sniffing the WAN side of the modem.   I'm not sure how you'd do that though.. I did see PPP traffic once but it was having a computer do the PPP connection and maybe I saw it with wireshark.   Also maybe there is a program that can analyze a router config file.  for example http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/router_password_recovery.html  and perhaps others.

Comment: @barlop okay sure I’ll try that and let you know

Comment: @barlop I was able to extract the 32 digit encrypted password from Chrome’s Inspect element. Putting it in an online MD5 hash decrypt converted it to the password I needed. However, on another same router, probably a different hardware version, the sequence is 64 digit hash, how can I decrypt that one because md5 is only 32 digits?

Comment: @AsadMoeen i'n no expert but a google suggests that md5 is 32 hex chars ie 16 bytes, 128 bits.  So this this one you ran into, seems to be twice that ie 256 bits.  Maybe it is a thing called SHA-256 so you could try an online SHA-256 decryptor

Comment: If you are still interested, paste the string from the config file. I can decrypt it for you